# How do I install XAMPP on Ubuntu?

Tags: xampp

It's way too complex for me. I need to use Localhost (PHP + MySQL)

Comment: Please use the search. This has been asked so many times on this site.

Answer (score 0):

This [webpage](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-xampp-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04/) should help you out.

Comment: That is only recommended if the OP really requires XAMPP and not regular LAMP. And also: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.